# Routing with express and firebase hosting

Tags: node.js, express, routes, firebase-hosting

I am new to using firebase hosting. I have a site that works fine locally, but when I deployed it to firebase causes a 404 error whenever I try to ajax to any endpoint that I have defined within my index.js file. I have looked at https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config, but it doesnt really make sense to me.

An example of my issue is that when the root of the site (/) loads, it ajaxs to an endpoint to get data from the database. On local host this ajax request works perfectly fine, but on the hosted site, I get a 404 error. This is the same for all of the endpoints that I have defined within index.js

My firebase.json looks like:

```
  "hosting": {
    "site": "mysitename",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/getInfo/",
        "destination": "/",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
  }
```

An example of something similar to what my index.js looks like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //serve index.html
});

app.get('/getInfo', (req, res) => {
    //do stuff here
});

app.post('/postInfo', (req, res) => {
    //do stuff here
});

app.post('/postSomeOtherInfo', (req, res) => {
    //do stuff here
});
```

How would I get it so that the routes defined within my index.js actually work, and dont give a 404 error? How would I make it so that if I ajax (or just go to) myapp/getInfo, myapp/postInfo, myapp/postSomeOtherInfo, etc, that it does what I have it doing in index.js, instead of returning a 404 error code?

Thanks!

Comment: may you inspect the network, check the request's header URL and validate it?! Since it's a GET request try pasting it into the browser URL bar and fire a request. Still 404?!

Comment: When I put the url in the url bar, it seems to go directly to the error function of the ajax request, even if I just do something like res.json({"hello":"World"});

Comment: Alright. Let me get this right, which part exactly is returning **404**, your backend server or firebase? Also are the frontend files being served by the same backend server and thus in the same host server?! I'm just trying to identify the responsible of **404** response.

Comment: Now it seems like somehow Im not getting a 404 error, but it is going directly into the error section of the ajax call, which I also have no Idea why. I seem to be a bit lost

Comment: No worries, but please help me to help you! answer my questions or edit your answer, add the whole flow so I can be able to re-produce.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out. I think I am going to take a break for a bit and come back to the problem later, with a fresh mind